# The property does not exist as the key has no associated value for the provided element

Tags: graph, graph-databases, gremlin

Can someone help me with the following issue,

```
gremlin> g.V().has("LOCATION", textContains('PADIASDS')).where(__.in().has('~label','Eqp_Vrtx').count().is(0)).emit().repeat(__.bothE().bothV()).times(1).path().unfold().dedup().order().by('MOUNT_POS')
```

The property does not exist as the key has no associated value for the provided element: v[41582720]:MOUNT_POS
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]N

The property of MOUNT_POS exists in the edges but not the vertices, which is why, when I try sorting the values above query gives me the reported error. I am trying to sort the edges alone but I also need both the vertices and edges in the resultset.

I am really looking forward to a fix on this as I have tried various ways to correct this but am not able to.

Appreciate if someone could assist me by fixing this.

**First Edit** - Also, the thing is I need the first few pieces of the gremlin query to be retained as this was already being deployed in production system and just needs to be sorted out by retaining the structure of the JSON data which I will get based on it and make use of.

Also, if you could just help me out to sort the edge property on an output of both the vertices and edges, it could be helpful.

Original Query:
`g.V().has("LOCATION", textContains('PADIASDS')).where(__.in().has('~label','Eqp_Vrtx').count().is(0)).emit().repeat(__.bothE().bothV()).times(1).path().unfold().dedup()`

Thanks,

Lalith

Comment: @Rubinsh  Can anyone help me with this issue? This one is being a priority and that's the reason, I have tagged few of the gremlin experts I came across on other gremlin posts

Answer (score 0):

[Same answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/FKbxWKG-YxA/kO1hc0BDCwAJ) as on the gremlin-users list: Append

```
.order().by(coalesce(values('MOUNTING_POSITION_NUMBER'), constant(""))
```